# Не работает команда join discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Раньше эта команда работала но сейчас нет. Подскажите почему

```
async def join(ctx):
    global voice
    channel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice=get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice=await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Бот присоеденился к:{channel}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def join_voice(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if connected:
        await connected.connect()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!